# Fragment prevents TextView in parent layout from rendering

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

After I embed a fragment into an activity, the widgets in the layout before the fragment fail to render. Widgets after the fragment render properly. If I move widgets from before the fragment to after the fragment, they also render. What's happening and how do I fix it?

Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".PlayerViewActivity">

    <!-- the following textview won't render -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/character_name_zzz"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:text="before" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/spell_list_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/character_class_zzz"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:text="after" />


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        style="@style/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation">

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the activity:

```java
public class PlayerViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_view);

        // init the fragment
        FragmentManager fragMan = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction txn = fragMan.beginTransaction();

        SpellListFragment spellListFragment = new SpellListFragment();
        txn.replace(R.id.spell_list_container, spellListFragment);

        txn.commit();
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the app with the code listed above. There should be a red TextView with the hardcoded word "before" below the toolbar and above the fragment. But there isn't:

[image: Screenshot of the layout misbehaving]

I don't see any exceptions in the log. I think the Choreographer complaint is because I paused execution of onCreate in the debugger.

```
2019-06-19 21:48:53.430 25455-25455/tome W/System.err: Took: 99
2019-06-19 21:48:53.484 25455-25455/tome D/ViewRootImpl@9e4df81[PlayerViewActivity]: setView = DecorView@152a826[PlayerViewActivity] TM=true MM=false
2019-06-19 21:48:53.496 25455-25455/tome D/ViewRootImpl@46e1c22[SpellScrollActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
2019-06-19 21:48:53.506 25455-25455/tome I/Choreographer: Skipped 1861 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2019-06-19 21:48:53.542 25455-25455/tome V/InputMethodManager: Not IME target window, ignoring
2019-06-19 21:48:53.554 25455-25455/tome D/ViewRootImpl@9e4df81[PlayerViewActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
2019-06-19 21:48:53.556 25455-25460/tome I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=503KB, data=343KB
2019-06-19 21:48:53.557 25455-25460/tome I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=503KB, data=289KB
2019-06-19 21:48:53.593 25455-25455/tome W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:2 lineCount:2
2019-06-19 21:48:53.605 25455-25460/tome I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=503KB, data=299KB
2019-06-19 21:48:53.606 25455-25460/tome I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=503KB, data=299KB
2019-06-19 21:48:53.606 25455-25460/tome I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 2MB
2019-06-19 21:48:53.654 25455-25455/tome V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
2019-06-19 21:48:53.655 25455-25455/tome D/ViewRootImpl@9e4df81[PlayerViewActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 496339603456} changed=true
2019-06-19 21:48:53.685 25455-25686/tome D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
2019-06-19 21:48:53.685 25455-25686/tome D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x738bcdc3b0
2019-06-19 21:48:53.888 25455-25686/tome D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x73907d6b30
2019-06-19 21:48:53.919 25455-25455/tome D/ViewRootImpl@46e1c22[SpellScrollActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true
2019-06-19 21:48:53.921 25455-25455/tome D/ViewRootImpl@9e4df81[PlayerViewActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
2019-06-19 21:48:53.925 25455-25455/tome D/ViewRootImpl@9e4df81[PlayerViewActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
2019-06-19 21:48:53.952 25455-25455/tome V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@90f856e nm : tome ic=null
2019-06-19 21:48:53.953 25455-25455/tome I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2019-06-19 21:48:54.035 25455-25455/tome D/ViewRootImpl@46e1c22[SpellScrollActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={valid=false 0} changed=false
```

When I comment out the `txn.commit()` from the activity, the "before" TextView renders:
[image: Without the fragment, the preceding TextView renders]

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Might have something to do with the layout_weight.  Can you try setting the framelayout layout_height to 0dp instead of wrap content? See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fragment contained a CoordinatorLayout with `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`. When I removed that, the fragment rendered properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ConstraintLayout as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- the following textview won't render -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/character_name_zzz"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:text="before" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/spell_list_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/color_primary"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/character_name_zzz"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/character_class_zzz"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/character_class_zzz"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:text="after" />


<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    style="@style/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Please put this answer as correct, if it works for you.

Comment: I tried the ConstraintLayout and I saw the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue is due to the way you have given weights, try making changes as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".PlayerViewActivity">

  <!-- the following textview won't render -->
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/character_name_zzz"
      style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
      android:text="before" />

  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/spell_list_container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1">
  </FrameLayout>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/character_class_zzz"
      style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
      android:text="after" />


  <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
      android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
      style="@style/bottom_navigation"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:menu="@menu/navigation">

  </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, using LinearLayouts with `layout_weight` will create an overhead of measuring each of its children twice. Therefore, consider using ConstraintLayout instead as it is more efficient than other layouts.

https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout

Comment: I didn't realize there was the added overhead, I'll give the ConstraintLayout a shot. Thanks!